# Сделать код на Python

Tags: python

Итак, мне нужно сделать код, но у меня не получается если что Python.

Есть такой вариант:

```py
n = int(input('Введите кол-во цифр ' ))
print(*sorted(int(input()) for _ in range(n)))
```

он впринципе рабочий но мне надо сделать подругому, а именно:
Мы задаём `N` тоесть количество чисел которое мы можем ввести,
далее мы вводим в строку тоесть цифры не как цифры а как слова и вводим эти цифры и потом эти числа сортируем. Не используя списки. Помогите ;)

Comment: опять учат паскалю на питоне)

Comment: ну или не как в строку а например сделать чтобы ввели N и тоесть на каждое число создавалась отдельная переменная

Comment: Не используя списки. - или брэйнфаку))

Comment: и я учу не паскаль а питон

Comment: надо отсортировать числа в строке не используя списки - я правильно понял?

Comment: да, правильно .

Comment: "на каждое число создавалась отдельная переменная" точно нужно?)

Comment: "на каждое число создавать переменную" - не надо так делать

Comment: не обязательно, можно и просто сделать возможным в текст строку ввести N чисел а потом сортировать ток не через sorted pls

Answer (score 0):

ну как вариант:

```
print(*sorted(input().split()))
```

правда `split()` скрыто создаёт список, но в явном виде - нет :)

можно так:

```
text = '1 4 2 6 -2'
print(*sorted(map(int, text.split())))
```

результат `map` - это не список, а просто итерируемый объект

P.S.

вместо `text` просто используйте `input()`, я статические данные использовал просто чтобы не вводить каждый раз текст

Comment: А где N задаём?

Comment: ну задайте его в самом начале - он все равно нигде не будет использоваться, из-за `split` в питоне надобности в N нет (если числа задаете в 1 строке), а во всяких тестах условие с N есть просто потому что задачи для разных языков задают одинаковые без заточки под каждый язык

Answer (score 0):

Мы задаём N

```
N = int(input())
```

каждое число создавалась отдельная переменная и числа как слова

```
for i in range(N):
  globals()['num'+str(i)] = input()
```

в итоге будут переменные num0...numN. сортировать их конечно можно, но только пузырьком скорее...

```
movs = True
while movs:
  movs = False
  for i in range(N-1):
    if globals()['num'+str(i)] > globals()['num'+str(i+1)]:
       movs = True
       globals()['num'+str(i)], globals()['num'+str(i+1)] = globals()['num'+str(i+1)], globals()['num'+str(i)]
```

вывод итога также как ввод

```
for i in range(N):
  print(globals()['num'+str(i)])
```

Comment: а вывод итога???

Comment: и еще конечно, можно попроще код а то не понятно после слова пузырьком))

Comment: может можно списки?) а то с соданием переменных всё становится пугающим

Comment: не, сказали списки нельзя, я так понимаю, N вводим
потом через for в строку добавляем постояяно значения пока в строке не будет N значение
потом их либо через sorted либо еще как то проще

Comment: я ж говорю паскалю учат на питоне... уточни где хранить числа до сортировки.)

Comment: вводим N 
потом создаём строку пускай stroka будет переменная
туда вводятся столько значений сколько N может както сделать типо в текст виде число и например 3 числа N и вводим 5 сначало потом 7 и тоесть как то чтобы 5 + 7 не 12 а 57 и так с ост числами пока не закончится возможность потом сортировка я не знаю как